# Create a column with lagging running total

Tags: sql

I have a table like below:

[image]

From values, I can easily get to cum_values using window function:

sum(values) over (order by id ASC rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as cum_values

How do I get cum_values_minus1, I tried a few iterations using "rows between", but they aren't working!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't cum_values_minus1 just cum_values - Values?

Comment: However would be good to know if this can be done independently using window functions